# ActionSheet? View? Not sure

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a screen with a button on a bottom toolbar which when the user clicks it I want a translucent screen to slide up from the bottom of the screen, the user will then enter something in a textbox, and then they can dismiss the screen.

Is this an ActionSheet? All I seem to find about ActionSheets are Buttons. It's not an Alert. So, is it a UIView? If so, I can't get the right animation nor find a way to set the opacity (just the alpha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an UIActionSheet is a list of buttons that appear from the bottom, and allow the user to select one of multiple options, like this:

http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3554/3480465538_f3a25e00e6_o.jpg

It doesn't allow users to type in values using the keyboard.

Alpha is opacity for RGBA colors. Instead of changing the opacity of the UIView, change the background color, and set the opacity of the color in that popup.

To make view slide on top of the other views, you can use the `PresentModalViewController(controller, true)` method in the UIViewController class.

I hope this helps.